# Opening files with an If in Python

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x, input

```
Profesor1= "Profesor-Materia.txt"
Profesor2= "Profesor-Año.txt"

input ("Seleccione un profesor: ")
if(input=="Profesor1"):
    file = open(Profesor1)
    data1= file.readlines(1)
    print(data1)
else:
    file = open(Profesor2)
    data = file.readlines(1)
    print(data)
```

So this is my code, I want to open The file: "Profesor-Año" whenever I input anything else than "Profesor1" but it just keeps opening the file "Profesor-Materia" even when I input something like: sadsadsad
Can you help me with this problem?
Ps: I've already tried using `if(input==Profesor1)`

Comment: Can you fix the formatting (especially the indentation) of the code in the question? In Python, indentation is significant, and it may not be possible to answer your question if we can't tell what the code actually looks like. The easiest way to format things is to paste in the code exactly as it is in your editor, then highlight it and press the `{}` button in the Stack Overflow editor (this indents everything by four extra spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has quite a few problems. Here is a proper version:

```
Profesor1 = "Profesor-Materia.txt"
Profesor2 = "Profesor-Año.txt"

in_text = str(input("Seleccione un profesor: "))
if(in_text != 'Profesor1'):
    file = open(Profesor2, 'r')
    data = file.readlines()
else:
    file = open(Profesor1, 'r')
    data = file.readlines()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is just checking that the variable `Profesor1` has something in it (see the Python docs on [truth value testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)), which it does. The user input is being ignored.

You need to change it to something like this:

```
prof = input ("Seleccione un profesor: ")
if(prof == Profesor1):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm just starting to program in Python so it's kinda new for me, it solved the problem n_n